# How to Declare array in stored procedure. Adding values to array through query. and iterating through a loop for array elements in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

How to Declare array in stored procedure. Adding values to array through query. and iterating through a loop for array elements in mssql stored procedure .

Comment: There are no arrays on SQL Server, can you clarify what you want?, it sounds like you want to iterate through rows from a table.

Comment: Yes exactly. I need to  iterate through rows from a table. How can i do this in stored procedure without array.

Comment: You might also want to give more information about why you want to loop over a table. In SQL Server code you should usually avoid doing that if possible, although there are certainly times when it's necessary. If you can explain more about what your problem is, someone may be able to help you avoid a loop completely.

Comment: I need to check if perticular entry is present in the table if present then update else insert.
I have multiple rows of data and i need to check each row

Comment: Updating else inserting (also referred to as a merge or sometimes an "upsert") has been asked about [dozens of times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+update+else+insert) already. I suggest you review the existing questions and if you're still stuck then explain what you've tried and why it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

TSQL does not provide arrays. Use [table variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx) instead.

Comment: How can i iterate through a column in table

Comment: I have multiple rows of data and i need to check each row

Answer (score 0):

To quickly answer this set of questions:

1) Rather than arrays you can use Table variables or temporary tables

2) To add values to array through query you can use `SELECT INTO` or `INSERT` statement

3) To iterate trough items you can use either `CURSOR` or `WHILE` loop